# Real World example of Spring prototype bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Prototype bean in spring creates a new instance and returns a new object every time the object is required. But I am unable to create/find a real world application example for this. I know it can be used when working with JMS or Spring Rest Services. But if my application is built using Spring MVC and Hibernate, where can we implement this feature of bean creation.

Comment: Hi, questions in this format are too broad and tend not to have a specific answer. See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. You might also want to create a topic request on SO Documentation!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475380/example-for-singleton-pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time you would need prototype spring beans in a multi-threaded application when each Thread needs to obtain a fresh Bean copy to avoid concurrency issues such as reading/writing on common data by all threads. If you use singletons in a multi-threaded application you may have very serious issues because each thread will share the common singleton and that may lead to all kinds of concurrency exceptions and unintented consequences.